# Appropriate way to deal with a 3-level contingency table

Tags: r, categorical-data, log-linear

I have a three level contingency table, with count data for several species, the host plant from which they were collected and whether that collection happened on a rainy day (this actually matters!). Using R, fake data might be something like this:

```
count    <- rpois(8, 10)
species  <- rep(c("a", "b"), 4)
host     <- rep(c("c","c", "d", "d"), 2)
rain     <- c(rep(0,4), rep(1,4))
my.table <- xtabs(count ~ host + species + rain)


, , rain = 0

    species
host  a  b
   c 12 15
   d 10 13

, , rain = 1

    species
host  a  b
   c 11 12
   d 12  7
```

Now, I want to know two things: Are species associated with host plants? Does "rain or not" effect this association? I used `loglm()` from `MASS` for this:

```
 # Are species independent to host plants, given the effect of rain?
loglm(~species + host + rain + species*rain + host*rain, data=my.table)

 # Given any relationship between host plants and species, does rain change it?
loglm(~species + host + rain + species*host)
```

This is a little outside my comfort level, and I wanted to check that I'd set the models up right and that this was the best way to approach these questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two ways to interpret your first question, which are reflected in the two ways you asked it: “Are species associated with host plants?” and, “Are species independent to host plants, given the effect of rain?”

The first interpretation corresponds to a model of *joint independence*, which states that species and hosts are dependent, but jointly independent of whether it rained:

$\quad p_{shr} = p_{sh} p_r$

where $p_{shr}$ is the probability that an observation falls into the $(s,h,r)$ cell where $s$ indexes species, $h$ host type, and $r$ rain value, $p_{sh}$ is the marginal probability of the $(s,h,\cdot)$ cell where we collapse over the rain variable, and $p_r$ is the marginal probability of rain.

The second interpretation corresponds to a model of *conditional independence*, which states that species and hosts are independent given whether it rained:

$\quad p_{sh|r} = p_{s|r}p_{h|r}$ or $p_{shr} = p_{sr}p_{hr} / p_r$

where $p_{sh|r}$ is the conditional probability of the $(s,h,r)$ cell, given a value of $r$.

You can test these models in R (`loglin` would work fine too but I’m more familiar with `glm`):

```
count <- c(12,15,10,13,11,12,12,7)
species <- rep(c("a", "b"), 4)
host <- rep(c("c","c", "d", "d"), 2)
rain <- c(rep(0,4), rep(1,4))
my.table <- xtabs(count ~ host + species + rain)
my.data <- as.data.frame.table(my.table)
mod0 <- glm(Freq ~ species + host + rain, data=my.data, family=poisson())
mod1 <- glm(Freq ~ species * host + rain, data=my.data, family=poisson())
mod2 <- glm(Freq ~ (species + host) * rain, data=my.data, family=poisson())
anova(mod0, mod1, test="Chi") #Test of joint independence
anova(mod0, mod2, test="Chi") #Test of conditional independence
```

Above, `mod1` corresponds to joint independence and `mod2` corresponds to conditional independence, whereas `mod0` corresponds to a *mutual independence* model $p_{shr} = p_s p_h p_r$. You can see the parameter estimates using `summary(mod2)`, etc. As usual, you should check to see if model assumptions are met. In the data you provided, the null model actually fits adequately.

A different way of approaching your first question would be to perform Fischer’s exact test (`fisher.test(xtabs(count ~ host + species))`) on the collapsed 2x2 table (first interpretation) or the Mantel-Haenszel test (`mantelhaen.test(xtabs(count ~ host + species + rain))`) for 2-stratified 2x2 tables or to write a permutation test that respects the stratification (second interpretation).

To paraphrase your second question, *Does the relationship between species and host depend on whether it rained?*

```
mod3 <- glm(Freq ~ species*host*rain - species:host:rain, data=my.data, family=poisson())
mod4 <- glm(Freq ~ species*host*rain, data=my.data, family=poisson())
anova(mod3, mod4, test=”Chi”)
pchisq(deviance(mod3), df.residual(mod3), lower=F)
```

The full model `mod4` is saturated, but you can test the effect in question by looking at the deviance of `mod3` as I've done above.

Comment: Thanks Lockedoff, especially for helping me sort out my own thinking w.r.t the difference between the conditional and joint independence model

Answer (score 1):

Initially I suggested to try one of the constrained ordination techniques from the `vegan` package, but on a second thought I doubt that this would be useful, as you actually have 2 contingency tables. I hope that the second part of [this example](http://is.gd/CSS9QV) [PDF: R Demonstration – Categorical Analysis] will be helpful.

Comment: Think the link is broken, did you mean [this categorical one here](http://biology.ucf.edu/~pascencio/classes/Methods/R%20demos/)? That was helpful, thanks!

Comment: Yes, it seems that the space in the URL breaks it.

Answer (score 1):

Logistic regression seems appropriate for your problem.  The variable you are trying to predict is the probability that an observation (which is either species A or species B) is species A.  The covariates are $host$, $rain$ and optionally $host*rain$.

The R command would be:

> glm(formula = species ~ host + rain, family = binomial(logit), weights=counts)

and you will be interested in the $p$-values of the slopes.  Keep in mind that you are testing multiple hypotheses, though.

Comment: Logistic regression seems ok, but it has the additional constraint of row and column total being fixed. This may not be the case with Poisson data. I believe the answers won't differ much.