# Test for independence in 3x2x2 table with small expected cell values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, independence, contingency-tables

I have three unordered categorical variables. I have made a 3x2x2 table, but I'm uncertain of how to test for independence. The usual manner is a chi-squared statistic, but I think this is inappropriate when the expected values of the cells are small. I have one cell that is 0, so this is an issue for me. In a 2x2 table, I think that the Fisher-Irwin exact test would work, but I can't find anything covering a table with three dimensions. Any ideas?

Comment: The actual value in a cell is not its expected value--but you seem to equate them. Could you clarify this by describing the typical *expected* values in the cells?  Even giving the total count would help, because we could divide that by $3\times 2\times 2 = 12$ to estimate an average expected value.

Comment: Sure - I should've included that in the original post, sorry. Total N is about 140 (so about 11.6 avg Exp Val).

Comment: Thank you.  Since most rules of thumb for applying the $\chi^2$ distribution deem "small" to be less than $5$ (maybe some really conservative ones use $10$ as a threshold), your average value of $11.6$ doesn't look small.  You therefore might not have any problem at all unless two or more of the *marginal* totals in this table are very imbalanced.  Perhaps you could display the entire table (since it's only 12 numbers)?

Comment: Look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243598/testing-for-contingency-table-with-three-variables,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8342/appropriate-way-to-deal-with-a-3-level-contingency-table,